# iOS Video Playback from RAM/Flash?

Tags: ios, iphone, flash, video, avfoundation

We are in the process of developing a simple game for iOS, specifically iPhone 5S. We have a
requirement to play a video in loop. For enhancing the performance we wanted to play the video
from RAM and retain the video in RAM (without fetching it from flash drive) during the subsequent iterations. Here is what we tried,

1. We tried to use the media framework, so the preparedtoplay function, brought the video clip
   from flash storage and did not retain the clip in RAM. We were able to observe this using the
   iOS instruments.
2. When we thought there is no way of doing this, we changed the player to AV foundation
   player and instead of using play / start, we performed a seek back to the start of the video. We observed the following,

• We tried loading videos of various sizes and the memory allocated on RAM always was +5
to 10 MB the size of the video. This we thought is due to application size and running the
application.

• We tried loading a large video, this was 160 MB with a playtime of 20 mins. In this case
only ~85 MB was allocated in the RAM. According to our hypothesis, at around 10 mins
CPU activity increased indicating decoding again.

• When smaller videos played CPU activity remained constant, after decoding was complete
before start of iteration 1 of video unlike the large video case.

Though apple does not provide the means to find out if the video is playing from RAM, based on
the above evidence and the trace sheets attached, can we safely assume the smaller
video is fully playing from the RAM and the flash reads have been minimised?
Point to note: we give a do nothing / hold function for 3 seconds after each loop.

**Trace before Start of Play :**

[image]

**Trace during Initial(1st) playback :**

[image]

**Trace during Initial(1st) loop hold :**

[image]

**Trace during 2nd playback :**

[image]